# Command Line Program for Converting XML to CSV

Tags: xml, csv, file-converter

I need a software for converting xml files to csv. It has to run on Windows Server 2012 / 2016 on command line. The software must have good support (updates, live help etc..)

Comment: Are you OK to write sample XSLT file?

Comment: hi yes can give it a go

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>",    </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position()  = last()">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>"<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And use `xsltproc` with this stylesheet to convert to CSV. For reference you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/365338/2908599

Also you can try this tool [`xml2csv`](https://github.com/fordfrog/xml2csv), it seems reported by people as working well.